# Symfony2 : Field error (error_bubbling)

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a pb with my form.
here is the definition of my property

```
  /**
 * @var integer $nbpointsTe
 * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
 * @Assert\Range(min=0)
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="NBPOINTS_TE", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $nbpointsTe;
```

here is the way I create the field in form

```
    $builder->add('nbPointsTe', null, array(
        'label'  => 'Nombre de points',
        'required'  => false,
    ));
```

My problem is : 
The error(s) of this field appear in my form and not next to my field.
I try to add 'error_bubbling' => false, but it doesn't change anything and the error keep going in the parent form. In addition this field doesn't display as a 'number' field automaticly (I know I could specify it in my builder if I replace null with 'number' but every other fields are correctly displayed without specifying that :/ )
The thing i don't understand is that I do the exact same things for others field and they display their errors without problem.

So if anybody sees something strange, or has a solution, feel free to comment :)

Thanks

Edit :

As asked my twig template: (nothing special here ^^ )
    {{ form_row(form.nbPointsTe) }}

I tried 'error_bubbling' => false, errors still display in my parent form :/

Comment: try with `'error_bubbling' => false` this should be default behavior...

Comment: Can you show us your twig template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I found what was the pb.

Symfony is case sensitive, so I added 'nbPointsTe' in my form and my class member was 'nbpointsTe' (Missing one Uppercase), and so nothing works. I just change one letter, and now everything is ok.

:)